# C Linked List adding and removing

Tags: c

```
typedef struct _readyQ {
    pcb_t *pcb;
    struct _readyQ  *next;
} readyQ;

static readyQ *ready_queue_head = NULL, *ready_queue_tail = NULL;
static void submit_ready_request(pcb_t *pcb);

static void submit_ready_request(pcb_t *pcb)
{
    readyQ *r;
    /* Build I/O Request */
    r = malloc(sizeof(readyQ));
    assert(r != NULL);
    r->pcb = pcb;
    r->next = NULL;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&readyQ_mutex);
    /* Add request to head of queue */
    if (ready_queue_tail != NULL)
    {
        ready_queue_tail->next = r;
        ready_queue_tail = r;
    }
    else
    {
        ready_queue_head = r;
        ready_queue_tail = r;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&readyQ_mutex);
}
```

initially head/tail are both NULL.
So, when I first add via submit_ready_request, i will go to else part

```
ready_queue_head = r;
ready_queue_tail = r;
```

both pointing at the same readyQ r.

Now when I add another one, it will go to

```
ready_queue_tail->next = r;
ready_queue_tail = r;
```

I was wondering in this case, 
`ready_queue_head->next` will point at r after the the code above is executed?

because i am trying to remove via this but its not working

```
readyQ *r;
r = malloc(sizeof(readyQ));
if (ready_queue_head != NULL) {   //not empty so remove
       r = ready_queue_head;  
       if(ready_queue_head->next != NULL){   
          ready_queue_head = ready_queue_head->next; 
        } else {    //only one in the queue
          ready_queue_head = NULL;
          ready_queue_tail = NULL;
       }
}
```

Comment: I looked quickly through it and do not see any obvious problems.  What indicates that it is not working?  Note that you do have a memory leak in the "remove" code.  The malloc is not necessary is is promptly leaked when r gets reassigned to the ready_queue_head.  Or is that maybe what indicates to you it is not working in that r is never NULL when removing?

Comment: its giving me segmenation fault (core dump) so something to do with memory while adding/removing. im not quite sure if its adding infinitly or.... whatnot

Comment: Remove the malloc() in your remove code, also, I suspect you also want to free(r) when you're done removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no `malloc()` should be required on a pop operation. Second, both your push and pop are overly pedantic. Stare at this push and pop logic *very* carefully, and don't incorporate it until you *know* how it works. You need to think how *both* work in concert to really grasp the simplicity.

First the push-logic. The following assumes `r` is the newly allocated node **with a next-pointer of NULL**:

```
if (ready_queue_head != NULL)
    ready_queue_tail->next = r;
else
    ready_queue_head = r;
ready_queue_tail = r;
```

Similarly, the pop-logic

```
r = ready_queue_head;
if (r != NULL) 
   ready_queue_head = r->next
```

Consider a few test cases in your head.

**Push Logic**

- What happens when you are inserting a new node in an empty list? Since the list is empty the head pointer will be NULL, so both the head and tail pointers will end up referencing the new node.
- What about inserting into a list with one element? Since the head pointer is non-null, there must also be a valid tail pointer, so set its next pointer to the new node, then the tail pointer to the new node.
- Does that change if there is more than one node in the list before the insert? Not at all.

**Pop Logic**

- What happens when you request a pop from an empty queue? Since the head pointer is NULL on an empty queue, the return value `r` will also be NULL.
- What happens when you request a pop from a single-element queue? The head pointer references the single element, so `r` will be properly set. Since `r` is non-null, the head pointer is advanced to its `next` pointer, which will be NULL. The list is now empty (head is NULL) and the return node pointer is set.
- What about a list with more than one node? Everything in the single-node-pop applies, but the head pointer will not be NULL on exit, so the list is still not empty (but *is* one element shorter than before. Again, the return node pointer `r` is properly set.

Anyway, I hope it helps. It is hard to fathom how little involved the tail pointer is in all of this, but not after you think about it for awhile As a bonus, this is the overtly complicated is-empty logic.

```
return (ready_queue_head != NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that when you say it is not working, you mean that `r` is not null after "removing" two nodes.  If so, then the error is this allocation in the removal code:

```
r = malloc(sizeof(readyQ));
```

If the list is empty, that would be the result (probably not desired).  And if the list is not empty, then that memory is promptly leaked.  It should probably just be:

```
r = NULL;
```

Comment: after i save the head to r, i send r to another function. well r->pcb.and if ready_queue_head == NULL, i just send NULL instead of r->pcb. so do i still need r = malloc(sizeof(readyQ)); or no?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  But I am pretty sure you do not need the malloc call when you are removing nodes (that would be a somewhat unlikely situation).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any errors (other than the spurious malloc), so compiled your code and didn't get any segfault or other error. The only thing I changed was removing the mutexes. Possibly the failure is in the mutex? Is your de-queue code protected by the mutex?

Also in answer to your question about ready_queue_head->next, yes it will work as you expected. In fact you could simplify your de-queue code to:

```
r = ready_queue_head;  
ready_queue_head = ready_queue_head->next; 
if (ready_queue_head == NULL){   
    ready_queue_tail = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
r = malloc(sizeof(readyQ));
```

The above statement will not allocate memory for a struct. Instead it will allocate memory for a pointer to a struct.

Comment: do i just get rid of that line?

Comment: readyQ is the type, that malloc would allocate memory for the struct